# Unable to pass dependency in Restangular config function(AngularJs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, restangular, jwt

I have the following code:

```
function configRestangular(RestangularProvider, BASE_URL) {
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(BASE_URL);
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

RestangularProvider.setErrorInterceptor(
    function (response, deferred) {
        if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
            //$state.go('login');
        }
    });
}

core.config(configRestangular);
```

When I pass `$localStorage` to function `configRestangular(RestangularProvider, BASE_URL)`, application throws an exception.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
>       Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.core due to:
>       Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $localStorage
>       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/$injector/unpr?p0=%24localStorage

I have registered the `ngStorage` module in main module. `ngStorage.js` file is also added in my main page. `$localStorage` service is working in all controllers except this config function.

I am using https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage module for localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add `'ngStorage'` and `'RestangularProvider'` as a dependency for your application:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngStorage','RestangularProvider']);
```

Comment: I have already declared 'ngStorage' and 'Restangular' dependencies.